# Can I Install Wubi on a Logical partition?

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi

My hard disk has 4 partitions:

1. System (primary partition)
2. C:(primary partition 200 GB)
3. F: (Logical drive 246 GB)
4. D: recovery(primary partition 20 GB)

Can I install 12.04 by WUBI installation method on the logical drive? If yes, can I shrink the remaining free space in `F:` drive to make another drive?

Comment: You can Install Wubi wherever you want, it Acts as a Windows program. and no you can't make another *partition* you already have 4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install `WUBI` on any of your "usable" drives(by usable I mean, partitions other than your `system` and your `recovery drives`). If you can backup the data on the F drive(if it matters to you), you can delete that partition first, create as many `logical partitions` under the new logical partition that you can create using this free space. At present it is not possible to create a new partition as [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) allows only 4 primary partitions and a logical partition is considered as a `primary partition` in this count. However, you can create any number of logical partitions inside a logical partition. That is why you need to delete this first. Hope you got it. Post it, if you have any problems.